# How to Automatically have Text Cursor in Text Box (as Opposed to Command Button Selected) in Form?

Tags: forms, vba, excel, excel-2007

I have two Excel picture objects linked to different forms, each with a text box and OK/Cancel buttons. In one form, the text cursor is in the textbox when clicking the object which is what I want: 
[image: Correct]

but in another it selects the OK command button rather than have the text cursor in the textbox: 
[image: Incorrect]

I've gone through the form and textbox/command button properties and see nothing about selection, and the 'correct' macro properties appear to be the same as the 'incorrect' one.

**What do I do to change the form such that when it's opened the text cursor goes to the textbox instead of the command button being selected?**

Comment: Have you tried `TextBox1.SetFocus`?  Replace "TextBox1" with whatever the name of your textbox is.

Comment: @David Zemens Where would I put this code? The only two event handlers I have are for cmdBtnOK_click and cmdBtnCancel_click. I've tried placing txtInstanceID.SetFocus in both handlers but there's no differences when opening which I guess because it's only called when the OK button is clicked, not before when the form is opened.

Comment: Add a UserForm_Initialize() event

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quite easy solution is to change `TabIndex Property` to 0.

So, **1)** go to VBA Editor, **2)** select your TextBox in your UserForm and **3)** change  `TabIndex` Property in Property window as presented below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add an event to the form so that when it is initialized it selects the correct texbox.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    TextBox2.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Before the form is displayed, you can do soemthing like:

`TextBox1.SetFocus`

Obviously, replace "TextBox1" with whatever the name of your textbox object is.

This should go in whatever event or macro causes the form to `.Show`, immediately before the `.Show` statement.

Comment: i have had problems using the SetFocus method in the past. never really understood why...